# Вывод массива в C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Пришел в C# из Python, и в Python, чтобы вывести массив нужно было ввести следующую строку:
'print (array)'. Как вывести массив в C#, без цикла?

Comment: [string.Join()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как и ответил **EvgeniyZ**:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var str = string.Join(" ", array);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
 int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

 Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", yourArray));
```

//Консоль:  [1, 2, 3]

Можно еще сделать екстеншн что бы было проще выводить в консоль в стиле питона.